# Navbar with custom menu list underline in javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, navbar

i've made a navbar. I used a custom script to display en effect on hover on the listed menu links: https://github.com/shadeed/underliner . I managed to make it work... partially.

The web page is responsive with a collapsable menu when < 990px.

The javascript function is called right before the < / ul > (i tried to put it somewhere else, but it doesn't work).

My first problem is that when the page is loaded with the normal menu (computer screen menu), it works. Even if i shrink the page it still works.
When the page is loaded with collapsed menu (< 990px screen menu), it doesn't work. Even if i expend the page, it dosn't work.
My guess is that when the navbar is collapsed the informations are called with data-target and aria-controls. And it doesn't run the javascript underline function in this case.

My second problem is that, whatever i try, i never success to make the collapsed menu list aligned in center when displayed on smartphone. (but the social section is correctly centered (but in another div)

```html
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent1" style="margin-top: 103px;">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 underliner">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#c94e37" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff6346" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="gradient2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#c94e37" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff6346" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
    </svg>
      <li class="nav-item c-nav__item"> <a class="nav-link" href="LINK1.html">LINK1</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item c-nav__item"> <a class="nav-link" href="LINK2.html">LINK2</a> </li>
  <li class="nav-item c-nav__item"> <a class="nav-link" href="LINK3.php">LINK3</a> </li>
   <script src="js/menu_soulignement.js"></script>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" style="align-items: : center">
<div class="container" style=" margin-top: 15px; align-items: : center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center" style="vertical-align: middle">
        <ul class="social-menu" style="align-content: center">
          <li><a href="http://twitter.com/mytwitter" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Suivez-moi @mytwitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aimez-moi #myfacebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/myinsta" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Admirez-moi @myinsta" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Épinglez-moi @mypint" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Regardez-moi #myyoutube" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you provide working snippet?

Comment: You can find my test project here : http://www.agence-mibe.com/TEST/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My first problem is that it works in desktop, not in mobile

It will works in desktop on load because your javascript is added total width of your every menu item on `svg` width but it not found any item on mobile so it set the width to 0.

so solution is added custom width to your `svg` so that problem will be solved

> How to center hover item

You can simply add `display: block; margin: auto;` in your `svg` and it will be a horizontally centered.

Comment: Thanks to you, i managed to center hover items, the underline is centered. But now i don't know why the links are displayed in "justify-content-space-around" and on tablet with landscape orientation the links aren't over the underline http://www.responsinator.com/?url=agence-mibe.com%2FTEST   :(

For the custom width to the SVG i tried to apply an "auto" "inherit" or 100% to it but it failed.

Comment: there are many questions available for how to apply width in SVG, so you can search it and I don't understand what you mean by `justify-content-space-around`

Comment: Thank you for your message, i red some of them since your first post https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ ; https://thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2019/03/09/view-box ;  ; http://soqr.fr/testsvg/embed-svg-liquid-layout-responsive-web-design.php . I think it has to do with a SCC attribute for the SVG so i made that :@media (max-width: 990px) {
 svg {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width : 100%; }
The underline is displayed but only on few pixels, i understand there are dependancies with viewport and view box

Comment: I think it has to do with a CSS (not SCC sorry)